# how to align input field and remove button cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml, cocoon-gem

I am trying to align my input field and remove button on my nested form. I am using rails 4, haml, BS4 and cocoon. This is what I have:

## _form.html.haml

```
    .row-fluid
        .col-md-12
            %h3 Bullet Points
            #bps-form
                = f.simple_fields_for :bps do |bp|
                    = render 'bp_fields', f: bp
                .links
                = link_to_add_association 'Add Bp', f, :bps,  class: 'btn btn-secondary add-button'
```

## _bp_fields.html.haml

```
.form-inline.clearfix
    .row
        .nested-fields
            = f.input :bp,  placeholder: "Enter a bullet point", label: false, input_html: { class: "form-input form-control", style: 'width:80%;'}

            = link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: "form-control btn btn-secondary", style: 'height:20%; display:inline; float:right;'
```

update[image]

Comment: Define "align": you want them aligned in one column, or one 1 line? You use `height` for the button, that should be `width`?

Comment: I added a screenshot of what is happening. I would like the remove button to be centered in the row with the text box instead of being under it